# Java cipher update vs IOS CommonCrypto update

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, encryption, commoncrypto

I am developing App for Android and IOS

For android I am using "AES/CBC/NoPadding" Cipher and for IOS am using CommonCrypto with same algo/mode/padding as Android

**I am initializing the ciphers with common key, for getting same result in both platforms**

In Android , am using `cipher.update(inpBuf, inpOffset, inpLen, outBuf, outOffset)` for encrypting/decryption purpose, same way I want to do it in IOS.

I Have tried **CCCryptorUpdate** in IOS , but the result array was [0,0,0......0]

Please guide me, where am gone wrong?

Comment: Unless your data to be encrypted is **always** a multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES) you need to add padding. This can be done manually (not suggested) or by using a supplied padding option such as PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5).

Answer (score 1):

AES is a block cipher that encrypts data in chunks of 16 bytes. When calling `update()` all blocks of 16 bytes will be encrypted and any excessive bytes will wait around until the next `update()` call.  When no more data needs encryption you finishes of the encryption with a `doFinal()` that flushes the last block + and applies any padding needed. Why are you using NoPadding? Are you ensuring you data matches the block size of AES yourself?

When decrypting in IOS you use the corosponding `CCCryptorUpdate()` and `CCCryptorFinal()`. Only after the `CCCryptorFinal()` you would have the full decrypted message. `CCCryptorUpdate()` might or might not return data, depending on how much is stuck in the buffer etc.

Comment: There is also the one-shot `CCCrypt` function which can be used in place of the `CCCryptorCreate`, `CCCryptorUpdate()`, `CCCryptorFinal()` and `CCCryptorRelease` calls.